# How to enable "rewrap text on resize" in Konsole?

Tags: ubuntu, resize, konsole

How to enable "rewrap text on resize" like feature in Konsole. When you use Terminal in Ubuntu, you will see that on resizing window multiple times, whole output text will rewrap again. I cannot see this feature in Konsole.

I don't want to use "screen" apt package for this problem.

[Konsole Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh9Oo.jpg)

Comment: This feature was finally added.  https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196998

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu's default terminal is gnome-terminal, which has the best implementation of text reflow I've personally seen.

Konsole is the default terminal application of distributions that use KDE. Text reflow in Konsole doesn't work as well as it does in gnome-terminal.

It is possible to install and use gnome-terminal on a KDE based distribution.